# No Module Named 'yfinance' in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio, yfinance

When trying to import the yfinance module in vs code I receive the problem `Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'yfinance' File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\yf.py", line 1, in <module> import yfinance as yf`

What's troubling is I have it installed under my python site-packages so I do not understand this issue

Comment: Open the command palette and select `python: select interpreter`, is it using the same interpreter you installed yfinance under?

Comment: Yes, that was the main issue I was facing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is common, dont worry.
Your problem is that you started your .py file to your terminal folder path that has not module.
Please go to the top-right corner, you will see "Run python file", if you press this and still get error, please create venv to try.

In terminal, type "py -3 -m venv .venv", and you will create a venv file, and please try to install yfinance again, and run your code, it should be fine if you know that you run the file in incorrect path terminal.